# MPAndroidChart добавить в метку Image

Tags: java, android

Использую BarChart библиотеки  `compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'`. Как сделать вместо номеров столбцов картинки.

```
        BarChart chart_lvl;   
        String [] values;

        chart_lvl = (BarChart) view.findViewById(R.id.chart_lvl);

        XAxis xAxis = chart_lvl.getXAxis();
                xAxis.setValueFormatter(new MyXAxi

        sValueFormatter(values));

            xAxis.setGranularity(1);
            xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
            xAxis.setLabelCount(10);
            chart_lvl.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);

            chart_lvl.setData(generateDataLVL(infoTexnikaRedactor.getInfografika_lvl_all()));
            chart_lvl.setFitBars(true); // make the x-axis fit exactly all bars
            chart_lvl.invalidate(); // refresh


        private BarData generateDataLVL(Infografika_lvl infografika_lvl) {


            List<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
            entries.add(new BarEntry(0, infografika_lvl.getLvl1()));
            entries.add(new BarEntry(1, infografika_lvl.getLvl2()));
            entries.add(new BarEntry(2, infografika_lvl.getLvl3()));
            entries.add(new BarEntry(3, infografika_lvl.getLvl4()));
            entries.add(new BarEntry(4, infografika_lvl.getLvl5()));
            entries.add(new BarEntry(5, infografika_lvl.getLvl6()));
            entries.add(new BarEntry(6, infografika_lvl.getLvl7()));
            entries.add(new BarEntry(7, infografika_lvl.getLvl8()));
            entries.add(new BarEntry(8, infografika_lvl.getLvl9()));
            entries.add(new BarEntry(9, infografika_lvl.getLvl10()));

            BarDataSet d = new BarDataSet(entries, "New DataSet ");
            d.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF8000"));
            d.setBarShadowColor(Color.rgb(203, 203, 203));
            d.setValueFormatter( new MyValueFormatter());
            ArrayList<IBarDataSet> sets = new ArrayList<IBarDataSet>();
            sets.add(d);

            BarData cd = new BarData(sets);
            cd.setBarWidth(0.8f);
            return cd;
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]